# Some of my files appear in multiple folders, how can I find and limit them to a single folder?

Tags: google-drive

In my Google Drive, I have hundreds of such files which appear in two locations: My Drive and DesiredFolder. For example, `cover.jpg` below appears in `My Drive` and `Pride and Prejudice (505)`.

[image]

I would like to find all files that are in `My Drive` and relegate them to DesiredFolder only.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I see when you select a file and Click on `Move To` then it shows where the current file reside already in pop-up. From there you can decide what to do with that file. Click on a new folder in the list, to Move To or to Existing folder to remove from the folder. At footer you should see create folder link.